# Defining the number of results when using the New York Times API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to fetch articles from New York Times using its article search API here at https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/articlesearch-product/1/routes/articlesearch.json/get
I just wanted to know what parameter I should use if I want to retrieve a pre-determined amount of results. The API gives you only ten results by default. How can I set the number of the results I want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is paginated, you can't request any more than 10 results at once:

https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/articlesearch-product/1/overview

> Pagination
>
> The Article Search API returns a max of 10 results at a time. The meta node in the response contains the total number of matches ("hits") and the current offset. Use the page query parameter to paginate thru results (page=0 for results 1-10, page=1 for 11-20, ...). You can paginate thru up to 100 pages (1,000 results). If you get too many results try filtering by date range.

Comment: So, what if I want to show more than 10 results on my page or less than that? Does it mean if I use two page parameters with two different page numbers, I can get 10 + 10 results for my query URLs?

Comment: You can make two requests to get two pages of results (10 + 10). You can't pass any parameters to a single request that will allow you to get more than ten results back.